# "Core Charge" on defective server HDDs

Tags: hard-drive, sas, scsi, hardware, smart

I have collected a pretty decent amount of SAS and SCSI disks over the years that have a predictive failure warning. I was just about to throw them all out, but wondered if any of the manufacturers offer a buy back program or maybe a credit toward the purchase of new hardware. Surely there are some scavengeable things inside of the disks that would be useful (other than the data!).

Does anyone know what I can do something useful with these "soon to fail disks", or at least get a few pennies on the dollar toward replacement costs?

Comment: What type of hardware is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you'd use your hardware warranty to exchange failed and *pre-failed* disks. This can come in the form of the server chassis warranty (HP/Dell, etc.) or even just the manufacturer's warranty.

Comment: I would love to but every piece of equipment was purchased from the secondary market, including the drives and any replacements. A hardware warranty and service contract would be like a dream!

Comment: @Brian I'm sorry. You can still leverage the warranty on HP equipment; especially used gear. And manufacturer warranties are just that. There may be some options.

Comment: For anyone with a similar situation HP has website that you can use to check the warranty status for their products, even if purchased used. http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/public/wc/home